# Issue with Python Slot Machine

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
        import random
        balance = 50

        def generator():
            slot = 0
            count = 0
            gen = random.random()
            while count < 3:
                count = count + 1
                if gen <= 0.01:
                        slot = 'Cherry'
                elif gen <= 0.06:
                        slot = 'Diamond'
                elif gen <= 0.16:
                        slot = 'Heart'
                elif gen <= 0.36:
                        slot = 'Spade'
                elif gen <= 0.66:
                        slot = 'Club'
                elif gen <= 1:
                        slot = 'Monkey'
                else:
                    break

            return slot


        def win(generator):
            if generator() == 'Monkey' and generator() == 'Monkey' and generator() == 'Monkey':
                balance = balance + 2122

        print "Welcome to the International Slot Machine"
        print ""
        print "Balance: $",balance
        print ''
        spinyn = (raw_input("Would you like to spin? $5 per spin. Enter y or n:\n"))
        while True:
            if spinyn == "y":
                break
            elif spinyn == "n":
                print "Final Balance: $",balance
                print "Thank you for using the International Slot Machine"
                raise SystemExit
            else:
                spinyn = raw_input('\033[31mPlease enter only y or n.\033[0m\n')

        spin = (raw_input("Press enter to spin for $5:\n"))
        while True:
            if spin == '':
                balance = balance - 5
                if balance <= 0:
                    print ""
                    print "Final Balance: $",balance
                    print "You have run out of money, the game has now ended."
                    raise SystemExit
                print ""
                print "\033[34mResult:\033[0m"
                print "\033[34m-------\033[0m"
                print generator()
                print generator()
                print generator()
                print ""
                print "New balance:$",balance
                print ""
                spinagain = (raw_input("Would you like to spin again? Press enter to spin again, type anything to exit.\n"))
                while True:
                    if spinagain == "":
                        break
                    else:
                        print "Final Balance: $",balance
                        print "Thank you for using the International Slot Machine"
                        raise SystemExit
            else:
                spin = (raw_input("Please press enter to spin.\n"))
```

I'm trying to make a very basic slot machine.

My question is: How do I make the generator function repeat 3 times and return 3 outputs, and then how do I make it recognise certain combinations?

Is this possible at all, keeping with my current format?

Also, how could I incorporate arrays into my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the range function to choose 3 times and store it in a list.

```
import random

choices_list=[]
for ctr in range(3):
    gen = random.choice(['Cherry', 'Diamond', 'Heart',
                     'Spade', 'Club', 'Monkey'])
    choices_list.append(gen)

print choices_list
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the generator return a list or tuple of three values after generating three values, also it would be easier to use `random.choice()` rather than `random.random()` . `random.choice()` randomly selects a element for a list of values/iterable with equal probability for all elements. Example -

```
def generator():
    ret = []
    for _ in range(3):
        ret.append(random.choice(['Cherry','Diamond','Heart','Spade','Club','Monkey']))
    return tuple(ret)
```

If you want to have different probabilities for different elements, you can keep the current method, just loop over that three times and append to `ret` like done above and return `ret` from it.

Then in your win function, keep a dictionary such that the key is the tuple of combination and the value is the amount the user wins, then you can simply use `.get()` with a default value of 0 , to get how much the user won. Do not pass in `generator` as an argument. Example -

```
def win():
    roll = generator()
    d = {('Monkey','Monkey','Monkey'):21222,...}
    return d.get(roll,0)
```

Then in your main loop, call this `win()` function to roll and see how much the user won.

Comment: Thank you very much, however I don't understand the def win() function?

Comment: What don't you understand in it? is it the dictionary `d` ?

Comment: @ScottMiller Keep in mind that `random.choice` will choose from the array with equal probability unlike your generator function which has different probabilties

Comment: @AnandSKumar I don't understand what it is doing.

Comment: you store the combinations and their corresponding win value in a dictionary. Then you call generator() to get the current roll . Then you use `dictionary.get()` to get the win value from the dictionary, you have also specified default value of `0` (as second argument) , so if the roll does not exist in the dictionary , we return a default value of 0, which means nothing is won, and then we return that value from the function.